# How do I send IDFA to Google Analytics from a Facebook ad click?

Tags: ios, facebook, google-analytics, facebook-ads-api, idfa

I am currently trying to get mobile app install attribution from Facebook ads. The goal here is something like this,

1. Create a Facebook ad that pings Google Analytics of the ad click.
      (Example URL :  https://click.google-analytics.com/redirect?tid=UA-324109-49&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fnl%2Fapp%2Fdrogisterij.net-mobiel%2Fid506652686&aid=com.drogisterijnet.drogisterijnet&**idfa=%{idfa}**)&cs=GAUC&cm=link&cn=Presentation
2. The ad is clicked and goes to Google Analytics and sends a hit for metrics in the URL params.
3. After sending the hit the user visits the destination in the App store where I can link the attribute the click of the ad to the installation through the IDFA (since IDFA is captured on install).

There is a Google Developer page that helps create this sort of redirect link here:     https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#url-builder

My issue is I do not know the macro used to get IDFA from the Facebook App .

Is it the same macro as the above link **idfa=%{idfa}**? I can not find any information on this other than where Facebook says

"The Facebook SDK for iOS only accesses IDFAs in the following scenarios: 1) if your app serves ads within the app through Facebook’s Audience Network, or 2) if your app logs app installs or other mobile App Events in order to attribute those events to your ad campaigns."

Link to above quote. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#IDFA

Am I going about this the wrong way or should I just be using a different macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you cannot. This is not something supported in Facebook ads.